# What is the server IP comment hack

Tags: comments

this is my first question about wordpress, because i don't know much about wordpress.

i have installed AntiSpam bee in my wordpress blog. And i got comments which marked as spam with the reason `Server IP`, that i got first time.

But i got shocked when i see that the comment don't had any **Email Address** .

but as i know that without any user name and email no one can send any comment to any post. Please someone help me to telling that what exactly happen or what i did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this if `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` of a ping/track back doesn’t match the IP address of the URL the ping back comes from allegedly.

Let’s say someone claims to send a ping back from `example.com` but the request IP and the server IP for `example.com` are different – the ping back is marked as spam.

The [documentation](http://playground.ebiene.de/antispam-bee-wordpress-plugin/) is not very clear about this, but a look at the source code told me everything <s>I</s> you wanted to know. :)